# Advice on testing Angular $localize (Angular 9)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-i18n

**Example repo**

The repo can be found [here](https://github.com/ross-moug/ng9-i18n-unit-test).

Please note that this isn't a complete example, it is merely there to show issues around testing `$localize`.

There are 2 branches:
 1. `master`
 1. `enable-localize-unit-tests` - this changes the `test.ts` and `polyfills.ts` to prevent the `@angular/localize/init` from being imported, the `$localize` global function is also spied

**Overview**

I have upgraded a project from Angular 8 to 9 (following the [Angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/)), replacing any usage the [`I18n`](https://github.com/ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill/blob/master/lib/src/i18n-polyfill.ts#L37) service (from the ngx-translation/i18n-polyfill) with Angular's new `$localize` function (documentation on this is pretty limited, [here](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/12/10/angular-localize/) is the best I could find). I can run localised builds and serve the application in a particular locale again. However, I've hit a bit of a roadblock when it comes to unit testing.

Previously, when using the `i18n-polyfill`, the `I18n` service could be injected into components, etc. as follows (see [`I18nPolyfillComponent`](https://github.com/ross-moug/ng9-i18n-unit-test/tree/master/src/app/i18n-polyfill)):

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-i18-polyfill",
  template: `<h4>{{ title }}</h4>
})
export class I18nPolyfillComponent {
  readonly title: string = this.i18n({
    id: "title",
    value: "Hello World!"
  });

  constructor(private i18n: I18n) {}
}
```

This could easily tested by injecting a spy into the component:

```js
describe("I18nPolyfillComponent", () => {
 let component: I18nPolyfillComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<I18nPolyfillComponent>;

  let mockI18n: Spy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ I18nPolyfillComponent ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: I18n,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpy("I18n"),
        },
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents().then(() => {
        mockI18n = TestBed.inject(I18n) as Spy;
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(I18nPolyfillComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    mockI18n.and.callFake((def: I18nDef) => def.value);
  });

  it("should call i18n once", () => {
    expect(mockI18n).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

However, I am unsure if similar unit tests could be written to test the usage of `$localize` as it is a global function rather than an injectable service.

For completeness the component would look like this using `$localize` (see [`I18nLocalizeComponent`](https://github.com/ross-moug/ng9-i18n-unit-test/tree/master/src/app/i18n-localize)):

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-i18n-localize",
  template: `<h4>{{ title }}</h4>
})
export class I18nLocalizeComponent {
  readonly title: string = $localize `:@@title:Hello World!`;
}
```

**Testing rationale**

I would like to ensure that my applications are interacting with `I18n`/`$localize` appropriately (called the correct number of times, with correct parameters, etc.). This just prevent silly errors if someone accidentally changes a trans-unit ID or the base translations value.

**What I've tried**

I have tried to replace the global `$localize` function with a spy in `test.ts` and avoiding importing `@angular/localize/init`:

```js
import Spy = jasmine.Spy;
import createSpy = jasmine.createSpy;

const _global: any = typeof global !== "undefined" && global;

_global.$localize = createSpy("$localize");

declare global {
  const $localize: Spy;
}
```

And then using the spied `$localize` in the tests (see :

```js
describe("I18nLocalizeComponent", () => {
 let component: I18nLocalizeComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<I18nLocalizeComponent>;

  let mockI18n: Spy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ I18nLocalizeComponent ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    $localize.calls.reset();
    $localize.and.returnValue("Hello World!);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(I18nLocalizeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it("should call $localize once", () => {
    expect($localize).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

The spy does work but tests will fail if the component, or another component, uses the `i18n` directives in it's template, for example ([`I18nLocalizeTemplateComponent`](https://github.com/ross-moug/ng9-i18n-unit-test/tree/master/src/app/i18n-localize-template)):

```html
<p i18n>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean consequat.</p>
```

This will fail with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
        at <Jasmine>
        at removeInnerTemplateTranslation (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:34560:1)
        at getTranslationForTemplate (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:34582:1)
        at i18nStartFirstPass (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:34771:1)
        at ɵɵi18nStart (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:34718:1)
        at ɵɵi18n (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:35450:1)
        at I18nLocalizeTemplateComponent_Template (ng:///I18nLocalizeTemplateComponent.js:15:9)
        at executeTemplate (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11949:1)
        at renderView (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11735:1)
        at renderComponent (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:13244:1)
        at renderChildComponents (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11538:1)
    Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/src/app/i18n-localize-template/i18n-localize-template.component.spec.ts:23:23)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to handle this use case or is it currently not supported? I haven't seen any documentation, tutorials or articles which help with this so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

To recreate the issue above in the example repo you'd have to:

1. Uncomment code in `test.ts`
2. Comment out import from `@angular/localize/init` in `polyfills.ts`
3. Run tests for `I18nLocalizeTemplateComponent`

The tests could be executed by using `npm run test -- --include src/app/i18n-localize-template/i18n-localize-template.component.spec.ts`

Alternatively, use [`enable-localize-unit-tests`](https://github.com/ross-moug/ng9-i18n-unit-test/tree/enable-localize-unit-tests) branch then follow step 3.

**Notes**

1. The following has been added to `polyfills.ts` for the project as per Angular upgrade guide:

   ```js
   import "@angular/localize/init";
   ```
2. I'm currently using Karma (`4.4.1`) and Jasmine (`3.5.9`) for unit testing

**Environment details**

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.0.6
Node: 13.2.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.0.6
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.900.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.900.6
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.900.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.900.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.900.6
@angular-devkit/core               9.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics         9.0.6
@angular/cdk                       9.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                   9.0.6
@schematics/angular                9.0.6
@schematics/update                 0.900.6
ng-packagr                         9.0.3
rxjs                               6.5.4
typescript                         3.7.5
webpack                            4.41.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found was to spy on the `translate` function of `$localize` rather than `$localize` itself:
**`test.ts`**

```js
const _global: any = typeof global !== "undefined" && global;
const defaultFakedLocalizeTranslate: (messageParts: TemplateStringsArray,
                                      substitutions: readonly any[]) => [TemplateStringsArray, readonly any[]] =
  (messageParts: TemplateStringsArray, substitutions: readonly any[]) => [messageParts, substitutions];

_global.mockLocalize = createSpy("mockLocalize") as Spy;

declare global {
  const mockLocalize: Spy;
}

$localize.translate = mockLocalize.and.callFake(defaultFakedLocalizeTranslate);
```

Make sure you have imported `@angular/localize/init` in `test.ts`.

The `I18nLocalizeComponent` unit tests can be updated as follows:

```js
describe('I18nLocalizeComponent', () => {
  let component: I18nLocalizeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<I18nLocalizeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ I18nLocalizeComponent ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockLocalize.calls.reset();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(I18nLocalizeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should call $localize once', () => {
    expect(mockLocalize).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

This change will also allow unit tests of component's with `i18n` tags in the template to run successfully as well.

To check out the changes see the [`fix-localize-unit-tests`](https://github.com/ross-moug/ng9-i18n-unit-test/tree/fix-localize-unit-tests) branch of the example repo.

Comment: Sadly, there doesn't seem to be an alternative for this in Jest. Since $localize is already a Function, not an object, Jest can't really do anything with it, as it can only spy on or create mocks of functions IN classes or objects and $localize is not a "real" object.

Answer (score 2):

#### Add i18n polyfill to your test setup as well.

Add  `import "@angular/localize/init"` to `test-setup.ts`

Answer (score 0):

CANNOT find name 'global'

For those who try to run it on Angular 12.

I had following issue
[image]

To make the demo running I had to add the following 
-> tsconfig.spec.json
add "node" to compiler options.

```
###tsconfig.spec.json

"compilerOptions": {
types": [
"jasmine",
"node"       <====
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer ist expanding the tests in the original posts.

For anyone who wants to test if 
the $localize translates the correct strings?

Here is how the test looks like:

```
it('should call $localize.translate with "string to translate"', () => {
    expect(mockLocalize.calls.argsFor(0)[0][0]).toContain('string to translate');
  });
```

Here is a [Repo](https://github.com/FlorianUhlmann/ng12-i18n-unit-test).
The Repo is a "fork" of the repo given in this post.

Differences:

- update on Angular 12
- added the test for translation-strings